# PFTableViewCell imageView is Nil (using storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've created a custom class that inherits from PFTableViewCell and for some reason the imageView is nil. Anybody know what the issue could be? I'm dequeuing the cell from the storyboard. When I completely programmatically generated the class it was fine. Here's my code.

PFTableViewCell has a property called imageView that should've been auto initialized from a child class (I thought).

class PhotoVC: PFQueryTableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell : PhotoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as PhotoCell!

    if cell == nil {
        cell = PhotoCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    println(cell.imageView) //Always prints nil
}
```

class PhotoCell: PFTableViewCell

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

When I try to add an IBOutlet for the imageView I get an error.

[image: error]

Comment: Do you have your cell view defined in storyboard? or you create your view programmatically?

Comment: My cell view is defined in the storyboard. @Keenle

Comment: Check if you have @IBOutlet for imageView and it is properly connected to the cell in storyboar.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error (I'll edit the question). @Keenle

Comment: Just add ! at the end of PFImageView and try again.

Comment: Same error (I had tried both).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57537/discussion-between-dehli-and-keenle).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the PFTableViewCell does not work well with standard styles. I took a glance at their code (it's open-source), and the comments indicate that they indeed have issues with imageView in the standard styles.

I suggest that you **create a custom cell with an imageView that you need to set as a PFImageView in the storyboard**.
Then the whole PFTableViewCell loading works fine (that's the only way it worked for me).